# Error in Event color display for 3 months in Full Calendar

Tags: php, json, ajax, fullcalendar

Im using FullCalendar v3.5.1 . For event display i have this below code.
But it works for short term event. For long term, like three months, the coloring done for first and last month and not for intermediate month. I understood that it draws the event color the month has start date or end date.

The event color shows for september from 25th and in november up to 12th. But no color in october month.

In my index.php file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('#travelCalendarBlock').fullCalendar({        
        height:400,      
        editable: true,
        defaultView: 'month',
        eventLimit: true,         
        events: modJs.getTravel(),      
        loading: function(bool) {
            if (bool) $('#loadingTravelCalendarBlock').show();
            else $('#loadingTravelCalendarBlock').hide();
        }

     // I tested using below commented code, it works fine
    /*  height:400,
        defaultView: 'month',
        defaultDate: "2017-09-01",
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true,
        selectable: true,        
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        events: [
            {
                title: 'Employee Leave',
                start: "2017-09-25",
                end: "2017-11-12",
                color: "#a4f0e3",
                textColor: "#190500"
            }
        ]*/

    });


In  javascript file


   EmployeeTravelCalendar.method('getTravel', function() {
        var url = this.moduleRelativeURL+"?a=ca&sa=getTravelsForMeAndSubordinates&t="+this.table+"&mod=modules%3Dtravelcal";
        return url;
    });
```

In travelcal.php file

```
public function getTravelsForMeAndSubordinates($req){

        $employeeTravel = new EmployeeTravelRecord();

        $req->start = strtotime($req->start);
        $req->end = strtotime($req->end);


        $startDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$req->start);
        $endDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$req->end);   

        $list = $employeeTravel->Find("((travel_date >= ? and travel_date <= ? ) or (return_date >= ? and return_date <= ?))",array($startDate,$endDate,$startDate,$endDate));

    $data = array();

        foreach($list as $leave){

            $data[] = $this->daytoEvent($leave);
        }   
        echo json_encode($data);
        exit();
    }


public function daytoEvent($leave, $leaveTypes){
        $event = array();
        $event['id'] = $leave->id;

        $event['title'] = $leave->employee." (".$leave->purpose.")";
        $event['start'] = $leave->travel_date; //2017-09-25
        $event['end'] = $leave->return_date;  //2017-11-15
        $eventBackgroundColor = "";     

        if($leave->type == "Local"){
            $eventBackgroundColor = "#a4f0e3";
            $eventTextColor = "#190500";
        }else{
            $eventBackgroundColor = "#c1a4f0";
            $eventTextColor = "#190500";
        }       

        $event['color'] = $eventBackgroundColor;
        $event['backgroundColor'] = $eventBackgroundColor;
        $event['textColor'] = $eventTextColor;

        return $event;
    }
```

This is the sample JSON:

```
[
  { "id":"46",
    "title":"AnuB (test)",
    "start":"2017-09-25 15:28:26",
    "end":"2017-11-12 15:28:26",
    "color":"#c1a4f0",
    "backgroundColor":"#c1a4f0",
    "tex‌​tColor":"#190500"
  }
]
```

Comment: Can't reproduce: http://jsfiddle.net/sbxpv25p/62/ . The colour shows across the whole duration of the event. Either your report is inaccurate, or something else which is not shown in your question is interfering with what you are seeing. However, if you can amend my JSFiddle link above such that it reproduces and demonstrates your problem, I would be interested to try and help. P.S. If you specify "color" then you don't need to specify "backgroundColor" at the same time - read https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/: "color 
sets an event's background _and_ border color"

Comment: Your code works exactly in my calendar block. i think problem in my code.JI edited my question that includes more code. Just look it.

Comment: Please can you show a sample of the JSON returned when you do `echo json_encode($data);`? (You can look into your browser's network tab, find the ajax request to your URL, and look at the response. It seems the problem must be in the data itself.

Comment: [{"id":"46","title":"AnuB (test)","start":"2017-09-25 15:28:26","end":"2017-11-12 15:28:26","color":"#c1a4f0","backgroundColor":"#c1a4f0","textColor":"#190500"}]     I got this from network -XHR Tab- Response

Comment: Still can't reproduce using your sample data and calendar settings: http://jsfiddle.net/sbxpv25p/63/ . I can only assume you've done something weird with your CSS maybe.